# How I make same FoatingActionButton on multiple pages, with a different actions depends on the what page its at

Tags: flutter

I have a bottomNavigationBar that includes some pages, I want to put same FAB on these screens but the same button have multiple actions, which depends on what page its at!
maybe knowing what page that TabBarView is showing will help but I cant reach this step.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check this repo https://github.com/ng-kode/whatsapp_clone

code snippet https://github.com/ng-kode/whatsapp_clone/blob/master/lib/home/home.dart

```
return Scaffold(
      body: ...
      floatingActionButton: buildFloatingActionButton(
        context,
        _tabController,
      ),
```

https://github.com/ng-kode/whatsapp_clone/blob/master/lib/home/build_floating_action_button.dart

```
buildFloatingActionButton(BuildContext context, TabController tabController) {
  if (getIsChatList(tabController)) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
          return SelectContact();
        }));
      },
      child: Icon(
        Icons.message,
      ),
    );
  } else if (getIsStatusList(tabController)) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
          return TabCamera(
            needScaffold: true,
          );
        }));
      },
      child: Icon(
        Icons.camera_alt,
      ),
    );
  } else if (getIsCallList(tabController)) {

    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
          return SelectCallContact();
        }));
      },
      child: Icon(
        Icons.add_call,
      ),
    );

  }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot , you made my day <3

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple instances of the floating action button for each different page and handle the logic individually. It doesn't need to be shared

Comment: I did it and it worked yes, all problem that I couldn't reach the _tabController.index